# Possible that some CANbus message are eaten?

Tags: can, esp32

I am developing a firmware update via CANbus 2.0B.
The client is written in python to send the firmware binary file to the receiver (an esp32-based custom pcb equipped with a CANbus transceiver). The communication runs at 500kbps.

Simply put, the protocole I ended up with is as follows: the client opens the firmware file, read 8-byte chunk and transmits the chunk of the file, to the receiver, which keeps track of the chunk index, starting from 0 and incrementing. On the receiver, on chunk reception, the chunk is written to the flash via a RAM buffer. The receiver keeping track of the index on its side as well, it sends a message back (with a different arbitration id) that contains the index in the payload. So that the client can compare the receiver index with its own and potentially emit a transmission error if they mismatch. The file to transfer is about 1.4MB. The whole process takes about 8 minutes.

My messages use normal communication (aka not a listener nor a no-ack). It does not use CANbus filtering either.

That kind of handshake works nicely when the mac that bears an USB peak adapter which itsel is connected via two wires to the esp32 pcb can high/low connector.

Now, the receiver is actually a battery and the esp32 pcb set in its enclosure.

The battery is itself inserted in a transport robot.
The battery communication port is connected to the comm port of the robot. That very CANbus port is located inside the chassis of the robot. But the robot has another CANbus port outside the chassis that is easily accessible.

So when I plug my peak to the « outside » port, and keep the robot turned off, the firmware update works nicely the same way it works in direct connection (aka straight to the battery), whilst I noticed a longer time to transfer (12 minutes).

Now, when the robot is turned on, the process stops working. It is kind of my messages are lost somewhere.

The CANbus communication itself seems to work: my client sees others standard messages coming from one of the robot devices.
The robot itself has 3 devices connected to the CANbus. Those devices use 500kbps as well. From the 3 devices two use standard frames while the third uses extended frames.

The robot manufacturer says the bus is low loaded (around 5% of the maximum).

What would potentially be the source of the problem?
What could I setup to better investigate the situation?

Comment: If a message is not ACKed after a certain number of resends it will as you say be eaten, this is done by the CAN controller. Each message on the bus must be ACKed as part of the protocol.It is possible is you are causing problems with the CAN bus proper. Check your termination. You should have 1 120 ohm resistor on each and none in the middle. There is another method using 2 60 Ohm on each end as well but it ends up being 120 Ohm. With the system powered down you should read about 60 Ohm on the bus += a few Ohms. If it is lower you have extra termination, if higher a terminator is missing.

Comment: Thanks @gil I will measure the résistance on the bus. But when the robot is turned off the resistance are still there or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like a difference in ground / common voltages when the robot is "on." Or noise from the robot interfering with CANbus.

Comment: Note that any node that receives the message can and will acknowledge it, even if your destination node didn’t receive it correctly it can still appear to be transmitted correctly. This is a dangerous protocol with no sequence numbering.

Comment: Regarding the protocol : The point is that the payload being 8 bytes max, adding an index (say 32-bit) will make the transfer twice longer. Would you do it? Also, I could add a 1-byte CRC so that the receiver can be « sure » the payload is ok which will prevent the issue you pointed?

Comment: A single byte sequence counter would suffice if you handle the rollover correctly. A CRC is not required as CAN already uses a CRC to validate messages. Implementing an reception message on the receiver side would work (send back a count of packets received that the transmitter validates) bit will be slower. If you’ve the address space you could implement a 4 bit or more sequence counter in an extended can address.

Comment: Errors never happen silently on a CAN bus, unless there is some software problem and a node refuses to send a message for whatever reason. Otherwise, all communication errors will be visible as CAN error frames on the bus. It is mandatory to have some manner of CAN listener when working with CAN bus, so plug yours in. Are there error messages or not? With a very busy bus with multiple nodes sending at the same time, "starvation" is also possible - but in that case only a symptom of a badly designed bus.

Comment: "The file to transfer is about 1.4MB. The whole process takes about 8 minutes." This doesn't add up. You have 1.4 * 1024 * 1024 * 8 bits. Multiply by 2 for a rough estimate of worst case CAN frame overhead bits. Multiply by 2 again for the receiver instantly echoing back the very same data. Then multiply by the bit speed 1/(500*10^3) to get the total time in seconds. `1.4*1024*1024*2*2*(1/(500*10^3)) = 94 seconds`. What am I missing here? Even if you send a whole overhead frame extra per 8 bytes of data it still doesn't add up.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but maybe still relevant for something

One way to send binary data is to use the ISO-TP protocol over CANBUS.

For more information check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15765-2, this allows sending a binary buffer up to 4095 bytes

[image: Frames in CAN-TP]
([source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/overview-iso-15765-2-aka-docan-protocol-saravana-pandian-annamalai-rizbc/))

### Delated explanation

https://www.embien.com/automotive-insights/demystifying-iso-15765-2-can-tp-docan-protocol

### Python module

https://can-isotp.readthedocs.io/

### CAN-ISOTP Linux module

https://github.com/hartkopp/can-isotp